# MongoDB : Parse each child and set flag recursively

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion, mongodb-query, aggregate

I would like to recursively parse each child's sub-child and set the flag to the child. Is it possible to do that using the mongo query with aggregate functions like "$graphLookup"

I am new to MongoDB, but I heard about the use of aggregate functions but not sure whether it can be achieved using mongo query itself?

```
My Collections Structure :

  Parent
  |
  |---Child1  // Depth 1
      |
      |---Sub child   // Depth 2
          |
          |---Sub Sub Child  // Depth 3
          ...
          ...
          |--- nth Child     // Depth n

  |---Child 2  // Depth 1
      |
      |---Sub child   // Depth 2
          |
          |---Sub Sub Child  // Depth 3
          ...
          ...
          |--- nth Child     // Depth n
```